# How to initialize field based on another field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, mongoid3

I have a user model with `:email` and `:user_name`, I want to auto initialize `:user_name` with part of `:email`.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :email
  field :user_name
end
```

I use simple_form to create the user.
How can I initialize `:user_name` based on `:email`?

Comment: Please answer question instead of editing...

Comment: can you give some example also?

Comment: did any of the answers solved your question or do you need further details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model:-

```
before_create :add_user_name

private
  def add_user_name
    self.user_name = self.email
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use default:

```
class User
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :email, type: String
 field :user_name, default: ->{ "email_is: #{email}" }
end
```

> "If you want to set a default with a dependency on the document's
>   state, self inside a lambda or proc evaluates to the document
>   instance."

See: [Mongoid fields documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#fields)

Tested with rails c:

```
u = User.new email: "name@domain.com"
u.user_name # => "email_is: name@domain.com"
```

Comment: No need to use self. self.email or email will do the work. Besides this will work even with users created in the database before the default user_name was implemented.

Comment: It throws error if not using `self.email` when create the user in rails console.

Comment: Which rails/mongoid versions are you using. It works for me tested with ruby 1.9.3, rails 3.2.0 and mongoid 3.1.5